# Replacing a define with a "test" define in CppUTest

Tags: c, cpputest

Is it possible, and if possible how, to replace a certain define with a define which is under control of the test framework?

For example, say the embedded system uses a define to access a port like so:

```
#define PORTA_CONFIG (*(volatile unsigned int*) (0x1000))
```

Now, I want to make sure that my "port module" is able to read/write to said PORTA_CONFIG correctly. How do I go about replacing `PORTA_CONFIG` with something like:

```
volatile unsigned int PORTA_CONFIG;
```

Comment: How about guarding the correct variables with `#ifdef TESTING ... #else ... #endif`?

Comment: You could switch to C++, which has reference variables. Short of that, you'll have to replace PORTA_CONFIG with a point variable, e.g., `volatile unsigned int *PORTA_CONFIG_ADDR` and change all references to PORTA_CONFIG to use the pointer variable.

Comment: @JimBalter We can't switch to C++ because embedded system :-)

Answer (score 1):

For production code you use:

```
//porta_config.h
...
#define PORTA_CONFIG (*(volatile unsigned int*) (0x1000))
```

While in you test project you use another header:

```
//porta_config_test.h
...
volatile unsigned int PORTA_CONFIG;
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to AudioDroid's answer, you can use different headers included by one *"facade header"*:

## The include approach (Test double)

**portconfig.h** a header to include the data - depending on what target you need (or if you are using it for testing)

```
#ifndef PORTCONFIG_H
#define PORTCONFIG_H

#ifdef TARGET_A
# include <portconfig_target_a.h> /* Use the config for target A */
#elif defined TARGET_B
# include <portconfig_target_b.h> /* Use the config for target B */
#elif defined TEST
# include <portconfig_testing.h> /* Use this instead for testing */
#else
# error "Not supported!" /* Just in case ... */
#endif

#endif /* PORTCONFIG_H */
```

Each of these header files contains these "defines" as they are required by the target, eg.

**portconfig_target_a.h**

```
...
#define PORTA_CONFIG (*(volatile unsigned int*) (0x1000))
...
```

or

**portconfig_testing.h**

```
...
volatile unsigned int PORTA_CONFIG;
...
```

This requires a `#ifdef` only at ***one central place*** and therefore has ***less maintenance effort***. Also there's no difference in target / testing code usage, `#include <portconfig.h>` is used in all cases.

## The abstraction approach

Instead of using `PORTA_CONFIG` directly, you can also ***abstract*** it into an ***function / macro***. For ***testing*** you ***can mock*** these.

```
typedef IOAddress ...
IOData IOData ...

void writePort(IOAddress addr, IOData data);
IOData readPort(IOAddress);
```

This has the benefit of abstraction and is very useful for testing.

There's an implementation and some great examples in [this repository](https://github.com/jwgrenning/tddec-code), especially `code` (MockIO, [header](https://github.com/jwgrenning/tddec-code/blob/master/code/mocks/MockIO.h), [implementation](https://github.com/jwgrenning/tddec-code/blob/master/code/mocks/MockIO.c), [example test](https://github.com/jwgrenning/tddec-code/blob/master/code/tests/IO/LegacyFlashTest.cpp)) - *using CppUTest*.

## See also

- [#include Test Double](http://www.renaissancesoftware.net/blog/archives/231)
- Test Driven Development for Embedded C *(James Grenning)*
- [Testing Code for Embedded Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572601/testing-code-for-embedded-application)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you intentions correctly, you could do something like:

```
#define TESTING

int main(){
#ifdef TESTING
    volatile unsigned int PORTA_CONFIG;
#else
    #define PORTA_CONFIG (*(volatile unsigned int*) (0x1000))
#endif
```

Comment: You did understand my intentions correctly however I/we try to steer away as much as possible from using `#ifdef TEST(ING)` constructions from production code, except for the main-file to hide the production-MAIN file from the testing framework (which has its own main-file)